# Annotation validation is not working in ASP .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an ASP .net MVC project in which I am using data annotation validator and it is not working. I am new to MVC .Please help me on this

My Model

```
 public class Home
    {
        public int i;

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string name;
    }
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Home h = new Home();
        return View(h);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Home h)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        //ModelState.AddModelError("name", "Enter  name");
        return View(h);
    }
```

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.name)


    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.name)


    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For DataAnnotation to work you need to define properties. So you need to have `get; set;`

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter")]
[StringLength(160)]
public string name { get; set; }
```